# laravel-cors not working with axios and vue-resource

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

As defined in documentation of **barryvdh/laravel-cors**, I've tried to implement *laravel-cors* on a **fresh installation of Laravel** but that doesn't work.

It yet gives the error of ***No Access Origin***.

I'm trying to access the post request using Axios on Quasar

Any assistance will be thanked.

**Specs**:

1. Laravel @ v5.4
2. Laravel-Cors @ v0.9.2
3. Axios @ v0.16.2
4. Quasar @ v0.14

[Laravel-Cors documentation ref.](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors)

> Works on Chrome if the extension of CORS is installed and enabled, but not the case without any extension in Firefox.

*Hence need to make it work without any extension on all browsers.*

Comment: How have you implemented it?

Comment: I added the Service provider, the global middleware, and published default config as guided in Documentation of laravel-cors. That's all I did.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `barryvdh/laravel-cors` to allow cors 
or 
just add this line 
 `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` in the `top` of  `controller` which will receive requests

and axios data will not just a JSON 
you should pass it as URL search parameter using `URLSearchParams` object 
example:

```
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('email', email_variable);
params.append('password', password_variable);

axios.post('url_here', params)
   .then();
```

Answer (score 0):

Also when you need to fetch post request from one url to another is it's necessary 
to set `mode: cors'`

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json',{
      method: 'post',
      mode: 'cors',
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((myJson) => {
    console.log(myJson);
  });
```